# Как вернуть результат асинхронного ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
function getFriends(id){
    var reqResult = $.ajax({
        url : url,
        data : {
            user_id : id,
        },
        type : "GET",
        dataType : "jsonp",
        success : function(data){
            return data;
        }
    });
}
```

Как сделать, чтобы функция `getFriends` возвращала результат ajax запроса?
Параметр `async` не влияет на это, так как ajax возвращает JSONP.

Comment: зачем вам jsonp?

Comment: api возвращает jsonp

Answer (score 1):

Используйте промисы:

```
function getFriends(id) {
        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                data: {
                    user_id: id,
                },
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "jsonp",
                success: resolve
            });
        });
    }
    getFriends(id).then(function(data) {
    //here is your data
    }, onReject)
```

Comment: `$.ajax` и так возвращает промис (deferred), можно просто его в данном случае возвращать, вы обернули в лишний)

Comment: Это понятно, но вопрос был 'Как сделать, чтобы функция getFriends возвращала результат ajax запроса'

Comment: Ну видимо не совсем понятно... `return $.ajax(...` – функция аналогично будет работать. Но если уж и отвечать на вопрос, то вернет результат только async функция, у вас она не результат возвращает)

Comment: Здесь под результатом имеется ввиду success : function(data){return data;} и реализация исходя из этого. Думаю автору так понятней будет. А вообще можно обойтись и одним колбеком

Comment: да нет, как раз в вопросе автор хочет этот ответ получить в возврате функции getFriends

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы был именно возврат результата, стоит использовать асинхронные функции:

```
async function getFriends(id) {
    return await $.ajax({
        url: url,
        data: {
            user_id: id,
        },
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "jsonp"
    });
}

const friends = await getFriends();
```